# Proper tables design

Tags: database-design

I am a novice in database design I am doing a small website (learning purpose).
In my scenario:

A user chooses a category (example categorie_A) and a list of questions appears. Each question has an answer (yes/non) and comment. When the form is submitted, I need to save it.
I would like to know if the following design is good?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is "myfield"?

Comment: It's a table that will keep each step. For a given category, a user will have multiple steps to fill (with multiple questions).